# Redirect stdout and stderr to file in Django with wsgi

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

I'm trying to make django work with wsgi in a shared hosting, so I cannot access server logs,

I'm trying to redirect the output to a file in my django.wsgi script, like this:

```
saveout = sys.stdout
log_out = open('out.log', 'w')  
sys.stdout = log_out
```

but this is the error that I have (in the only error log that I can access)

```
[Thu Oct 07 19:18:08 2010] [error] [client <ip>]   File "/home/myuser/public_html/django.wsgi", line 9, in <module>
[Thu Oct 07 19:18:08 2010] [error] [client <ip>] mod_wsgi (pid=30677): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/myuser/public_html/django.wsgi'.
```

and that is all the error I can get

Line 9 is the one that tries to open file. I've tried creating previously the file, giving writing access to everyone, without the file previously created.. and nothing.
In the app, I only get a 500 server error.

Is there a proper way to get this output without access to apache logs?

Edited:

Using absolute paths, I can open files and write to them, but I get empty files unless I close the files in the end, is it necessary? Could I leave the files open?..

Regarding to the initial problem, even though I used exception handling, write a "finish ok" to file in the end of my script, then close the file, but still get the error:

```
[Thu Oct 07 13:33:07 2010] [error] [client <ip>] mod_wsgi (pid=32541): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/myuser/public_html/django.wsgi'.
```

If I intentionally raise an error, it is logged in the file, so as i get "ok" I think the script worked fine but the result is still that message error... no clues

Answer (score 3):

You can't use relative pathnames like `out.log` in a WSGI application. WSGI doesn't specify where the working directory will be pointing and mod_wsgi doesn't set it unless specifically asked to in daemon mode.

Use an absolute pathname based on your application's root. You can use `os.path.dirname(__file__)` to get the directory containing the current script/module if needed.